# Install older version of Google Photos on iphone 6

Tags: ios, google-photos

I just received a reset iPhone 6 from a friend. I would like to install Google Photos but this app needs iOS14. Now the iphone 6 can be upgraded up to iOS12.5.5 and no more.

Is there a way I can install and older version of Google Photos on this iphone?

Comment: Not really, since i haven't purchased the app in question before...Also things might have changed a lot from iOS7 to iOS12

Comment: The answer for iOS12 is the same as for iOS7.

Comment: You are right, there is NO ANSWER. What is written for iOS7 is NOT USEFUL. And that's not kind to close a question only because you are not able to answer it.

Comment: It‘s not about me not being able to answer, it‘s about the answer being the same for iOS 12 as it was for iOS 7: Only if you installed an app version compatible with iOS 12 before, you will be able to download it again.